# How to insert or update rows in the intermediate table of a many-to-many relationship if the table has extra columns?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I know how to insert/update rows into the intermediate table of a many-to-many relationship if the table has only the foreign key columns :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String role_code;

    private String role_lib;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_menu" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")} )
    private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();

    public Role() {
        super();
    }

    public Role(String role_lib) {
        super();
        this.role_lib = role_lib;
    }

    public Role(String role_lib, Set<Menu> menus) {
        super();
        this.role_lib = role_lib;
        this.menus = menus;
    }

    public String getRole_code() {
        return role_code;
    }

    public void setRole_code(String role_code) {
        this.role_code = role_code;
    }

    public String getRole_lib() {
        return role_lib;
    }

    public void setRole_lib(String role_lib) {
        this.role_lib = role_lib;
    }

    public Set<Menu> getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }

    public void setMenus(Set<Menu> menus) {
        this.menus = menus;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="s_menu", sequenceName="s_menu", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="s_menu")
    private int menu_id;

    private Integer gmnu_code;

    private String menu_lib;

    private Integer menu_ordre;

    private Integer menu_visible;

    private Integer menu_deleted;

    private Integer menu_bouton;

    private Integer menu_parent;

    private String menu_controlleur;

    private String menu_navigation;

    private Integer menu_flag_trace;

    private String menu_trace;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "menus")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    @Transient
    private int depth;

    @Transient
    private Environment env;

    public Menu() {
        super();
    }

    public Menu(Integer gmnu_code, String menu_lib, Integer menu_ordre, Integer menu_visible, Integer menu_deleted, Integer menu_bouton, Integer menu_parent, String menu_controlleur, String menu_navigation, Integer menu_flag_trace, String menu_trace) {
        super();
        this.gmnu_code = gmnu_code;
        this.menu_lib = menu_lib;
        this.menu_ordre = menu_ordre;
        this.menu_visible = menu_visible;
        this.menu_deleted = menu_deleted;
        this.menu_bouton = menu_bouton;
        this.menu_parent = menu_parent;
        this.menu_controlleur = menu_controlleur;
        this.menu_navigation = menu_navigation;
        this.menu_flag_trace = menu_flag_trace;
        this.menu_trace = menu_trace;
    }

    public Menu(Integer gmnu_code, String menu_lib, Integer menu_ordre, Integer menu_visible, Integer menu_deleted, Integer menu_bouton, Integer menu_parent, String menu_controlleur, String menu_navigation, Integer menu_flag_trace, String menu_trace, Set<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.gmnu_code = gmnu_code;
        this.menu_lib = menu_lib;
        this.menu_ordre = menu_ordre;
        this.menu_visible = menu_visible;
        this.menu_deleted = menu_deleted;
        this.menu_bouton = menu_bouton;
        this.menu_parent = menu_parent;
        this.menu_controlleur = menu_controlleur;
        this.menu_navigation = menu_navigation;
        this.menu_flag_trace = menu_flag_trace;
        this.menu_trace = menu_trace;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public int getMenu_id() {
        return menu_id;
    }

    public void setMenu_id(int menu_id) {
        this.menu_id = menu_id;
    }

    public Integer getGmnu_code() {
        return gmnu_code;
    }

    public void setGmnu_code(Integer gmnu_code) {
        this.gmnu_code = gmnu_code;
    }

    public String getMenu_lib() {
        return menu_lib;
    }

    public void setMenu_lib(String menu_lib) {
        this.menu_lib = menu_lib;
    }

    public Integer getMenu_ordre() {
        return menu_ordre;
    }

    public void setMenu_ordre(Integer menu_ordre) {
        this.menu_ordre = menu_ordre;
    }

    public Integer getMenu_visible() {
        return menu_visible;
    }

    public void setMenu_visible(Integer menu_visible) {
        this.menu_visible = menu_visible;
    }

    public Integer getMenu_deleted() {
        return menu_deleted;
    }

    public void setMenu_deleted(Integer menu_deleted) {
        this.menu_deleted = menu_deleted;
    }

    public Integer getMenu_bouton() {
        return menu_bouton;
    }

    public void setMenu_bouton(Integer menu_bouton) {
        this.menu_bouton = menu_bouton;
    }

    public Integer getMenu_parent() {
        return menu_parent;
    }

    public void setMenu_parent(Integer menu_parent) {
        this.menu_parent = menu_parent;
    }

    public String getMenu_controlleur() {
        return menu_controlleur;
    }

    public void setMenu_controlleur(String menu_controlleur) {
        this.menu_controlleur = menu_controlleur;
    }

    public String getMenu_navigation() {
        if (this.env != null)
            return env.getProperty(menu_navigation);
        return menu_navigation;
    }

    public void setMenu_navigation(String menu_navigation) {
        this.menu_navigation = menu_navigation;
    }

    public String getMenu_trace() {
        if (this.env != null)
            return env.getProperty(menu_trace);
        return menu_trace;
    }

    public void setMenu_trace(String menu_trace) {
        this.menu_trace = menu_trace;
    }

    public Integer getMenu_flag_trace() {
        return menu_flag_trace;
    }

    public void setMenu_flag_trace(Integer menu_flag_trace) {
        this.menu_flag_trace = menu_flag_trace;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void setEnv(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/role")
public class AdminRole {

    @Autowired
    private MenuDAO menuDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDao;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView attribuerMenus(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) { // inserting rows into the intermediate table

        String role_code = "";

        Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) { // input name : param.getKey() , input value : param.getValue()

            if (param.getKey().equals(new String("role_code")))

                role_code = param.getValue();

            else

                menus.add(menuDao.get(Integer.parseInt(param.getValue())));

        }

        roleDao.insertRoleMenus(roleDao.get(role_code), menus);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/role/");

    }

}

public class RoleDAOImpl implements RoleDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public RoleDAOImpl() {
        super();
    }

    public RoleDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super();
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Role get(String role_code) {

        return (Role) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Role.class, role_code);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertRoleMenus(Role role, Set<Menu> menuSet) {

        role.setMenus(menuSet);

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(role);

    }

}
```

Now if the intermediate table "role_menu" has an extra column , say `some_column varchar2(100)` , how can I insert / update data into this column "some_column" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create entity for it:

```
@Entity
RoleMenu  
@ManyToOne Menu
@ManyToOne Role
String some_column
```

use one to many in existing classes:

```
@OneToMany
RoleMenu
```

Comment: ok , I will try it later but now there are other things I m doing :)